# Form Submit on Dialog window opens a blank page in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, jsp

I have searched all over looking at similar questions but unfortunately none seem to quite work for me.
I have a Dialog Form which opens up on-click in parent document. After editing the values, the form is submitted to java servlet, closes the dialog and returns to parent. Everything works fine after in Chrome or Firefox, however in IE it opens up a blank page with the response URL.
A solution shall be very helpful but any pointers should be fine.

The parent JSP:

```
<body class="yui3-skin-sam">
    <center>
        <div id="ok">
        <h1>NBReports</h1>
        <p>New business on call reports</p><br/>        
        <input type="button" value="Add Row" align="right" onclick="javascript: showWindow(window, 1)" /><br/>      
        <div id="tblReportSchedule"></div><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Add Row" align="right" onclick="javascript: showWindow(window, 1)" />
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function showWindow(obj, bEdit)
{   
    if(bEdit == 1)
        {
            openModal("updateSchedule.jsp", 600, 450);
        }
    else if(bEdit == 2)
        {   
            var rowID = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id; 
            openModal("updateSchedule.jsp", 600, 450, getAllRowValuesbyID(rowID));
        }
    else 
        {
            var rowID = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id; 
            openModal("updateSchedule.jsp", 300, 200, getAllRowValuesbyID(rowID).split("/")[0]);            
        }
}

function getAllRowValuesbyID(rowID)
{
    var rowValues="";
    row = document.getElementById(rowID);

    for (var i = 0; i < row.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if((window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('windows') == -1) )
        {
            var node = row.childNodes[i];
            rowValues += node.textContent + "/";
        }
        else
        {
            var node = row.children[i];
            rowValues += node.outerText + "/";  
        }
    }
    return rowValues;
}

function openModal(url, width, height, rowValues)
{
    var features = "";
    if (width != "")
    {
    features = features + "dialogWidth:" + width + "px;";
    }
    if (height != "")
    {
        features = features + "dialogHeight:" + height + "px;";
    }

    var retVal = window.showModalDialog(url, rowValues, features);  

    if(retVal)
    {
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
}

</script>

</html>
```

The dialog Form:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Update Schedule Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onSubmit()
    {
        window.returnValue = "";
        if((window.opType == 3) || window.dirtyFlag)
        {   
            window.dirtyFlag = 1;
            window.returnValue = getValue('cronTab') + '/' + 
                                 getValue('reportName') + '/' +
                                 getValue('subject') + '/' +
                                 getValue('recipient') + '/' +
                                 getValue('cc') + '/' +
                                 getValue('database') + '/' +
                                 getValue('script') + '/' +
                                 getValue('format');
        }
        window.close();
    }

    function getValue(varName)
    {
        if(document.getElementById(varName) == null)
            return "";
        if(document.getElementById(varName).value == null)
            return "";
        else
            return document.getElementById(varName).value;
    }

    function setdirtybit()
    {
        window.dirtyFlag = 1;
    } 

    function SubmitForm()
    {
        if(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') == -1)
        {
            if(window.dirtyFlag || window.opType == 3)
            {
                document.forms["UpdateSchedule"].method="get";
                document.forms["UpdateSchedule"].action="/nbreports/updates";
                document.forms["UpdateSchedule"].target="_self";
                document.forms["UpdateSchedule"].submit();
            }
        }
    }

    function GenerateSubmit(valText)
    {
        var submitButton = "";
        if(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1)
            submitButton = "<center><input type ='submit' value='" + valText + "' onclick='onSubmit()' /></center>";            
        else
            submitButton = "<center><input type ='button' value='" + valText + "' onclick='onSubmit()' /></center>";

        return submitButton;
    }   

    window.onbeforeunload = SubmitForm;
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <form name="UpdateSchedule" id = "UpdateSchedule" action="/nbreports/updates" method="get">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var valuesArray = new Array();
        if(typeof window.dialogArguments == "undefined")
        {
            var idArray=["cronTab","reportName","subject","recipient","cc","database","script","format"];
            var nameArray=["CronTab","Report Name","Message Subject","Recipient List","Cc","Database","Script","Format"];

            var str = "<table cellpadding = '2' border = '0'>";

            for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                str += "<tr>";
                str += "<td><label for='" + nameArray[i]+"'>" + nameArray[i] + "</label></td>"; 
                if(i==3 || i==4){
                    str += "<td><input style='width:450px' type ='text' id='" + idArray[i] + "' name='" + nameArray[i] + "' onchange='setdirtybit()' /></td>";
                }
                else{str += "<td><input style='width:200px' type ='text' id='" + idArray[i] + "' name='" + nameArray[i] + "' onchange='setdirtybit()' /></td>";}
                str += "</tr>";
            }
            str += "<tr style='display: none;'><input type='hidden' name='opType' value='1' /></tr>";
            str += "</table>";

            document.write(str);        
            document.write(GenerateSubmit("Submit"));   
        }
        else 
        {
            valuesArray=window.dialogArguments.split("/");
            if(valuesArray.length == 1)
            {
                document.write("<center><label>Are you sure you want to delete the row?</label><br/><br/></center>");
                document.write("<input type='hidden' name='id' value='"+ valuesArray[0] +"' />");
                document.write("<input type='hidden' name='opType' value='3' />");
                document.write(GenerateSubmit("Ok"));
                window.opType = 3;
            }
            else
            {       
                var idArray=["cronTab","reportName","subject","recipient","cc","database","script","format","id"];
                var nameArray=["CronTab","Report Name","Message Subject","Recipient List","Cc","Database","Script","Format", "Id"];

                var str = "<table cellpadding = \"2\" border = \"0\">";

                for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                    str += "<tr>";
                    str += "<td><label for='" + nameArray[i]+"'>" + nameArray[i] + "</label></td>"; 
                    if(i==3 || i==4){
                        str += "<td><input style='width:450px' type ='text' id='" + idArray[i] + "' name='" + nameArray[i] + "' onchange='setdirtybit()' /></td>";
                    }
                    else{str += "<td><input style='width:200px' type ='text' id='" + idArray[i] + "' name='" + nameArray[i] + "' onchange='setdirtybit()' /></td>";}
                    str += "</tr>";
                }
                str += "<tr style='display: none;'><input  type ='hidden' name='id' value='"+ valuesArray[0] +"'/></tr>";
                str += "<tr style='display: none;'><input  type ='hidden' name='opType' value='2' /></tr>";
                str += "</table>";

                document.write(str);
                for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                    document.forms[0].elements[nameArray[i]].value = valuesArray[i+1];
                }
                document.write(GenerateSubmit("Submit"));
            }
        }               
        </script>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of document.write(); Can you replace it with using innerHTMl?!
Instead of,
document.write(str);
Document.write(GenerateSubmit("Submit"));
Try,
document.getElementById("submitNode").innerHTML = str+GenerateSubmit("Submit");

Remember to add a div element inside the form with id "submitNode". Like this: